# How to adjust default keycloack endpoint to return more values from https://domain.tld/admin/realms/myrealm/users/?

Tags: keycloak

I have made keycloack rest api client, but default response dont return users roles and user groups . Is  there way to achive this? I found that this is possible by retriving multiple endpoints ... But can we just add these two values in existing endpoints and how ?

Update:
I didnt find way how to add it in api https://domain.tld/admin/realms/myrelam/users/
but you can add it "https://domain.tld/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo" ,
but I client scope we can add mappers for roles, and there we can retrive informations form jwt token